# What exactly does "is a pre" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idioms

In the context of a job advertisement, what does "is a pre" mean?

Top and only useful result on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="is+a+pre") was [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/experience-is-a-pre.1899451/), only guessing "[pré-requis](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/pr%C3%A9-requis/fr-fr/)" (requirement), which makes it odd to include sporadically in a list of job *requirements* like this PDF section:

> **Job Qualification**
>       • M.Sc. / BSc. in software engineering or equivalent.
>       • 7+ years of experience in Software design.
>       • (Must) Experience in writing Python.
>       • Experience in writing embedded C-code.
>       • Experience with Labview **is a pre**.
>       • Experience in FPGA design and prototyping **is a pre**.
>       • Knowledge of scripting languages.
>       • Good communication skills, team player, driver mentality, pro-active attitude.
>       • Networking skills, creative, motivating, curious, open minded.
>       • Able to identify and resolve complex issues.
>       • Fluent English speaker.

And especially this recruiter quote:

> Skills must:
>       •   Ruby
>
> Skills **pre**:
>       •   Ruby on Rails
>       •   Java

Comment: It's either a typo of, or unnecessarily sloppy shorthand for **preferred**, as in "these skills aren't required, but they are good to have". I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the misleading use of an improperly abbreviated term.  "Pre-" has a meaning, but this isn't it.

Comment: @Andrew - In this context, I would assume "is a pre" is shorthand for "is a prerequisite".

Comment: @J.R.  Sure, you would think that -- but again, it's not.  The unqualified skills (computer degree, job experience, etc.) are the prerequisites.  The ones marked with "pre" are the "nice to haves".  I've received hundreds of these, and they're all similarly structured (although I have yet to read one that used this awful abbreviation).  I have a bad feeling it's become "CS recruiter slang".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "is a" portion used in the first example indicates that "pre" is a noun, and I am inclined to think you are correct that it is short for "prerequisite". Of course, the example also includes "(Must)" which should indicate the same thing, so there is a lack of internal consistency.

In the second example, however, the "pre" category is contrasted with "must". I would interpret this as short for "preferred", meaning skills which would reflect well on the applicant but are not required.

Answer (score 4):

It is a poorly translated Dutch sentence. In Dutch 'pre' means not strictly required but good/nice to have or a plus. See [this dictionary entry (in Dutch)](https://www.vandale.nl/gratis-woordenboek/nederlands/betekenis/pre).

Answer (score 0):

It probably means prerequisite, but I am not sure if it's a typo, because people would say it's an incorrect usage as it doesn't make sense to use a "word", if you can call it that, that's so ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

In general,

**pre-** is used to form words that indicate that something takes place before a particular date, period, or event. [Def.](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pre)

For the above, I believe you have stuck upon the correct usage.

> - Experience with Labview is a pre.

I.e.

> - Experience with Labview is a required.

Comment: In this context it's shorthand specifically for "prerequisite."

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it more, I think it _could_ be a typo for "... is a **plus**." Meaning having Labview experience would be a bonus but is _not_ required.

Comment: @TypeIA Agreed on the shorthand, sorry if I didn't make that clear in my answer! (+1) Disagree on the typo, since it's repeated, making it unlikely :)

Comment: The recruiter quote convinces me it's either a typo (yes, repeated) or bad English. The recruiter refers to "pre" skills in contrast to "must" skills, so I'd stake my application on it meaning "plus."

Comment: This is incorrect. Assuming it follows the typical pattern for these kind of requests, it's either shorthand for, or a typo of, **preferred**.